# Serializing an XML with C# and Serialize class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize this XML and I have majority of it done, but I'd like to categorize the information correctly, here is my current output.

```xml
<CountryData>
    <CountryName Type="Text">United States of America</CountryName>
    <CountryName Type="Text">Kingdom of Belgium</CountryName>
    <CountryCode Type="Text">US</CountryCode >
    <CountryCode Type="Text">BE</CountryCode >
    <PercentOfBusiness Type="Numeric">0.5</PercentOfBusiness>
    <PercentOfBusiness Type="Numeric">0.5</PercentOfBusiness>
    <AverageBusiness Type="Numeric">3.5%</AverageBusiness >
    <AverageBusiness Type="Numeric">3.5%</AverageBusiness >
    <SalesMade Type="Text">Very low </SalesMade >
    <SalesMade Type="Text">Low</SalesMade >
</CountryData>
```

But I would like it like this

```xml
<CountryData>
    <Country>
         <CountryName Type="Text">United States of America</CountryName>              
         <CountryCode Type="Text">US</CountryCode >         
         <PercentOfBusiness Type="Numeric">0.5</PercentOfBusiness>
         <AverageBusiness Type="Numeric">3.5</AverageBusiness >
         <SalesMade Type="Text">Very low</SalesMade >
    </Country>
    <Country>
         <CountryName Type="Text">Kingdom of Belgium</CountryName>
         <CountryCode Type="Text">BE</CountryCode >
         <PercentOfBusiness Type="Numeric">0.5</PercentOfBusiness>
         <AverageBusiness Type="Numeric">3.5</AverageBusiness >
         <SalesMade Type="Text">low</SalesMade >
     </Country>
</CountryData>
```

Here is what I have

```cs
public class CountryData
{
    #region Public Members
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> CountryName = new List<string>();
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> Countrycode= new List<string>();
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> PercentOfBusiness = new List<string>();
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> AverageBusiness= new List<string>();
    [XmlElement]
    public List<string> SalesMade= new List<string>();

    ...
}
```

Then I set those variables to w/e values I have from my feed and serialize

```cs
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriter writer;

settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "  ";
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
serializer.Serialize(writer, CountryData);
writer.Close();
return sb.ToString();
```

Would I need to change the way that I instantiate my serialize object? Also would it be possible to remove the Data type information for each node (e.g. CountryName Type = "Text")

Thanks.

Comment: Download SharpSerializer from Nuget.

Answer (score 6):

You want to have `CountryData` class to contain list of countries, like so:

```
public class CountryData
{
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    public CountryData() { Countries = new List<Country>(); }
}

public class Country
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Countrycode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PercentOfBusiness { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string AverageBusiness { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string SalesMade { get; set; }
}
```

It will produce a little different xml then the one you asked for but it makes sense:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <CountryData
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <Countries>
            <Country>
                <CountryName>name</CountryName>
                <Countrycode>code</Countrycode>
                <PercentOfBusiness>12</PercentOfBusiness>
                <AverageBusiness>123</AverageBusiness>
                <SalesMade>120012</SalesMade>
           </Country>
           <Country>
                <CountryName>name2</CountryName>
                <Countrycode>code2</Countrycode>
                <PercentOfBusiness>34</PercentOfBusiness>
                <AverageBusiness>345</AverageBusiness>
                <SalesMade>453453543</SalesMade>
           </Country>
    </Countries>
</CountryData>
```

---

#### Main method

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CountryData));
        var subReq = new CountryData();
        subReq.Countries.Add(new Country
        {
            CountryName = "name",
            Countrycode = "code",
            PercentOfBusiness = "12",
            AverageBusiness = "123",
            SalesMade = "120012"
        });
        subReq.Countries.Add(new Country
        {
            CountryName = "name2",
            Countrycode = "code2",
            PercentOfBusiness = "34",
            AverageBusiness = "345",
            SalesMade = "453453543"
        });
        var xml = "";

        using (var sww = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
                xml = sww.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what object am i instantiating in my class where i popualte my data?

Comment: I instantiated this `XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CountryData));`. I can't see your entire code architecture, so I did my serialization a little different, but idea should stay the same: having list of countries inside `CountryData`

Comment: ok and in my main method where i assign the values                                                          public Country Execute(Country Countries) ??? and then i call that from my main script ?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you are asking. I updated my example with minimum amount of code needed to generate xml string to answer the original question.

Comment: i moved all of that stuff into a seperate class / method and i want to call it from my main script do i instantite a new object of country and call the method?

Comment: Sure. Instantiate your new object where you encapsulated all this code, have some method that returns your xml string and call it. Also, I made [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nG3ZWS)

Comment: Ok got it to work but the XML format is incorrect says extra chars present, is it the " thatu set to var xml?

Comment: I don't know where that error comes from, as I don't know about life cycle of this xml string after it is returned. Maybe it could be backslash `\ ` that escapes double quote symbol `"`? This could be a new question. EDIT: Or maybe it could be "\r\n" because your have that setting `settings.Indent = true;` maybe?